# Struct and Arrays limit problems

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct

I've been working on my Model Loader and I got an error because I use several structs with arrays (no vectors), I want to initialize the array before use it because the program gives me error when I try to use to access the vector array with brackets [].

GameObject struct:

```
struct GameObject
{
    int ID, parent;
    string tag;
    Mesh_t Mesh;
    Vector3 position;
    Vector3 scale;
    Quaternion rotation;
    Color color;
};
```

Meshes struct:

```
struct Meshes_t
{
    vector<GLfloat> VBO;
    vector<GLfloat> VBO_Normal;
    Texture_t Texture;
    DWORD Geometry;
    int VertexType;
};

struct Mesh_t
{
    int VerticesCount;
    int TexturesCount;
    vector<Meshes_t> Faces;
};
```

And the problem is when I try to push_back to VBO vector array from "Meshes_t" like this:

```
GameObjects[GameObjectsCount].Mesh.Faces[k].VBO.push_back(vertex.x);
GameObjects[GameObjectsCount].Mesh.Faces[k].VBO.push_back(vertex.y);
GameObjects[GameObjectsCount].Mesh.Faces[k].VBO.push_back(vertex.z);
```

Due to Faces vector array is not initialized anywhere Visual Studio throws me a runtime error when the program reach the code below: this is the error https://gyazo.com/806e3426025ad3885f0d3ed0b7aa1d30

I tried to initialize the vector array but I don't know how to do it because the vector array has other struct inside and I can't push back struct data. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is the gameobjects array from .h

```
extern struct GameObject GameObjects[1000];
```

and cpp is struct GameObject GameObjects[1000];

so I use this to create gameobject:

```
int teste = Entity.CreateEntity("data//models//cube.obj", Vector3(0, 25, 0), Quaternion(0, 0, 0), Vector3(0.51, 0.51, 0.51), -1);
```

and the int returned is what I use in GameObjects[ReturnedINT]

RENDER FUNCTION:

```
void GLRender ()
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    RenderSpaceLines();

    drawLine(Vector3(0, 0, 0), GameObjects[0].position);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        for (int i = 0; i < Entity.GameObjectsCount; i++)
        {
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
            if (GameObjects[i].Mesh.TexturesCount > 0)
            {
                for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++)
                {
                    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (GLfloat*)GameObjects[i].Mesh.Faces[t].VBO.data());
                    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, (GLfloat*)GameObjects[i].Mesh.Faces[t].Texture.VBO.data());

                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureManager.GetTextureFromName(GameObjects[i].Mesh.Faces[t].Texture.TextureName));

                    glPushMatrix();
                    glPushAttrib(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                    if (GameObjects[i].parent == -1)
                    {
                        glTranslatef(GameObjects[i].position.x, GameObjects[i].position.y, GameObjects[i].position.z);
                        glRotatef(GameObjects[i].rotation.x, 1, 0, 0);
                        glRotatef(GameObjects[i].rotation.y, 0, 1, 0);
                        glRotatef(GameObjects[i].rotation.z, 0, 0, 1);
                    }
                    else  ///RELATIVITY OF ENTITY TO ANOTHER
                    {
                        glTranslatef(GameObjects[GameObjects[i].parent].position.x,
                            GameObjects[GameObjects[i].parent].position.y,
                            GameObjects[GameObjects[i].parent].position.z);                 ///SET WORLD RELATIVE POSITION

                        glRotatef(GameObjects[GameObjects[i].parent].rotation.x, 1, 0, 0);
                        glRotatef(GameObjects[GameObjects[i].parent].rotation.y, 0, 1, 0);
                        glRotatef(GameObjects[GameObjects[i].parent].rotation.z, 0, 0, 1);

                        glTranslatef(GameObjects[i].position.x,
                            GameObjects[i].position.y,
                            GameObjects[i].position.z);

                    }
                    glScalef(GameObjects[i].scale.x,
                        GameObjects[i].scale.y,
                        GameObjects[i].scale.z);

                    glDrawArrays(GameObjects[i].Mesh.Faces[t].Geometry, 0, GameObjects[i].Mesh.Faces[t].VertexType);
                    glPopMatrix();
                }
            }

        }

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to show how is `GameObjects` declared and how you're currently trying to initialize it.

Comment: Your statement "I use several structs with arrays (no vectors)" is contradicted by the definitions you posted. And there is usually no problem using `push_back` with structs.

Comment: I edited the post with more info and how could I push_back a struct? I tried and VS gave me errors "no appropiate default constructor available" any mini-example would be grateful :)

Comment: That error probably means that you are pushing_back an object of the wrong type, and that the compiler tries to construct the right one for you. `VBO` is a `vector<GLfloat>`, so you should push_back a `GLfloat`. You are pushing_back `vertex.x`. Is `vertex.x` a `GLfloat`? I guess it isn't, and then the compiler is trying to find a `GLfloat` constructor that takes as argument the type of `vertex.x`. If it's missing, it will give you an error. Can you check whether this is what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Faces` is actually initialized in the implicit default constructor of `Mesh_t`. But it will be empty. So, before accessing `Faces[k]` you must first put at least `k + 1` elements into the vector. For example:

```
GameObjects[GameObjectsCount].Mesh.Faces.resize(k + 1);
GameObjects[GameObjectsCount].Mesh.Faces[k].VBO.push_back(vertex.x);
// ...
```

Also make sure that `GameObjects` has at least `GameObjectsCount + 1` objects.

Comment: This works but when I try to load a cilinder with 1450 faces for example the game fps decreases to 1 or 2 FPS, the problem is not on the render function because I tested with only 10 loops in each main loop and it's still lagged, here is my render function, post edited. In the code only will draw 10 vertex because the loop is 10 times.